# Order Confirmation Email Sent before Payment Success in Magento 1.9

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

When I order any item from my store then place order I got order confirmation email before payment success. I used Magento 1.9.1. This issue is major.
Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can disable order confirmation email. You can disable this from configuration->sales Email->order confirmation.
Or you can manually change function of controller.

Answer (score 4):

This is how Magento Order Email works.

1. When User Place Order he will get Order Confirmation Email.
2. When Payment Received, user will get Invoice Email for Payment Confirmation.

If you want you can disable order Confirmation Email. So that when Payment Received User Will get Invoice Email and you can modify the same as per your requirement.

You can disbale the emails from : `System >> Configuration >> Sales Email`